# numpy.where with like operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I would like to use `np.where`, but need to match a string using a wildcard. Is this possible, or is there another function that is best to be used in this scenario?

```
df['PRODUCT'] = np.where(df['TYPE'] == '2b', 'Pencil',
                np.where(df['TYPE'] like 'I5%', 'Ruler', 0))
```

I tried using the `in` operator, however this did not work.

```
df['PRODUCT'] = np.where(df['TYPE'] == '2b', 'Pencil',
                np.where('I5' in df['TYPE'], 'Ruler', 0))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['PRODUCT'] = np.where(df['TYPE'] == '2b', 'Pencil',
                np.where(df['TYPE'].str.contains('I5'), 'Ruler', 0))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE':['2b','2c','I5','I5 a', 'a I5']})
print (df)
   TYPE
0    2b
1    2c
2    I5
3  I5 a
4  a I5

df['PRODUCT'] = np.where(df['TYPE'] == '2b', 'Pencil',
                np.where(df['TYPE'].str.contains('I5'), 'Ruler', 0))

print (df)
   TYPE PRODUCT
0    2b  Pencil
1    2c       0
2    I5   Ruler
3  I5 a   Ruler
4  a I5   Ruler
```

If need check only starts of string add `^`:

```
df['PRODUCT'] = np.where(df['TYPE'] == '2b', 'Pencil',
                np.where(df['TYPE'].str.contains('^I5'), 'Ruler', 0))

print (df)
   TYPE PRODUCT
0    2b  Pencil
1    2c       0
2    I5   Ruler
3  I5 a   Ruler
4  a I5       0
```

Comment: Glad can help you!